# Target instance object by using a variable value in Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animate-cc

I have a series of objects each with instance names such as:

object1
object2
object3

going up in numerical order. I want to access each one depending on the value of a variable. For example

```
myVar:Num = 2;
```

I would like to use this value to select the appropriate object. In javascript or JQuery would be written like this:

```
object + myVar
```

Which would return me object2. However, this approach is obviously not working in AS3. Can anybody help me put please?

Comment: If you want to get "myThing2" you would do this["myThing"+myVar] or if you want property 2 on myThing it would be this.myThing[myVar] I think you want the first one though.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'll give that a go. I'm assuming 'this' refer to the current timeline  the instance is located in?  What if I wanted to access the parent or root timeline?

Comment: You can't start a line with a "[" so you need to specify what object you want to look for this property on so either yourClass["thing"+num] or this["thing"+num] or parent["thing"+num] , however you need to reference it. Depends on the structure of your code.

Comment: Thanks. And to access the root timeline would be root["thing" + num]?

Comment: Depends if this is in a class or in the actions panel (or if it is nested in a movieclip). If "root" will give you access to the root timeline than yes that is correct.